# Tracking incremental changes of serialized objects

Tags: r, serialization

This is really out of pure interest and I know it's not even close to being efficient.

But: is it possible to track incremental changes of a serialized object in R so that I only need to save the increments instead of the whole object on every change and then retrieving the "complete" object by piecing together incremental information? This probably does not make sense in the first place as it's cheaper to serialize the entire object anew, but I'd just like to broaden my horizon a bit ;-)

I'm not really familiar with raw vectors, binary formats etc., but doesn't backup software, for example, do something like this (incremental backups)?

This is how I got so far

```
x.1 <- 1
s.1 <- serialize(x.1, connection=NULL)
x.2 <- c(x.1, 2) 
s.2 <- serialize(x.2, connection=NULL)
x.3 <- x.2
x.3[2] <- 99
s.3 <- serialize(x.3, connection=NULL)

> s.1
 [1] 58 0a 00 00 00 02 00 02 0e 00 00 02 03 00 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 01 3f f0 00
[26] 00 00 00 00 00
> s.2
 [1] 58 0a 00 00 00 02 00 02 0e 00 00 02 03 00 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 02 3f f0 00
[26] 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> s.3
 [1] 58 0a 00 00 00 02 00 02 0e 00 00 02 03 00 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 02 3f f0 00
[26] 00 00 00 00 00 40 58 c0 00 00 00 00 00
```

Now I wondered what would be a feasible way to keep track of which bytes were altered (s.1 vs. s.2, s.2 vs. s.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems you'd need to define two functions, say "vdiff" and "vpatch" (there is already a "diff" function in R, so "vector diff" is the best I could come up with).

The "vdiff" function would analyze two vectors and output a bunch of replacements. Each replacement would be something like "replace the range `r` of `x` with `b`", so two integers (from/length) to denote the range `r` and a byte vector `b`. This covers three cases:

1. Remove a section from `x` (`b` is empty)
2. Insert a section (`r`'s lentgh is `0`)
3. Replace a section (`r`'s length is positive and `b` is non-empty).

Each replacement can be represented as `list(from=6, length=2, bytes=11:14)`, and grouped together in a list.

The `vpatch` function would take the bunch of replacements and apply them to `x` to recreate `y`.

Now, the `vdiff` function is complicated and I don't have time to implement it. In the example below, I've hard-coded it to return the correct diff object for the specified `x` and `y`.

...I leave it as "an exercise for the reader" to implement fully ;-)

The `vpatch` function however, is complete:

```
# Dummy hard-coded function
vdiff <- function(x,y) {
   list( list(from=1, length=0, bytes=as.raw(101:103)),
         list(from=7, length=3, bytes=raw()),
         list(from=11, length=0, bytes=as.raw(111:113)) )
}

vpatch <- function(x,d) {
   for (r in d) {
      pre <- if (r$from == 1) raw(0) else x[1:(r$from-1)]
      post <- if (r$from > length(x)) raw(0) else x[(r$from+r$length):length(x)]
      x <- c(pre, r$bytes, post)
   }
   x
}

# Sample vectors
x <- as.raw(1:10)
y <- as.raw(c(101:103, 1:3, 7:10, 111:113))

d <- vdiff(x,y) # Create diff from x to y
y2 <- vpatch(x, d) # Apply diff to x to get y
identical(y, y2) # TRUE
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll play around with it a bit and get back with results here